# Marge multpile column in new one in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split

I have a problem to create a new column with data of existing.

e.x
[image]

I have a big file with more than 20k rows and want to do in CARD column template to show the static text (black) and the variable (red).

I'm trying with `=` function, but not work.
Maybe You know another way to do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [`CONCATENATE()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function will do the task

`CONCATENATE("my ID is ", A1, " and my Name is ", B1)`

[image]

Comment: you couls also concatenate with the command going


="my ID is " & A1 & " and my Name is " & B1